# Linux how to make the space similar with previous

Tags: linux, sh

I have an input and which to replace certain (row,column) . 
I have done to replace the (row,Columnn) that needed but how come the whole line formate was shift? 
Any code need to add in to prevent the format changes?

**Code that i am using to replace the (row,column)**

> cat abc.txt | awk '$1 ~/^0(1?[0-9])|^00(1?[0-9])$/' | awk '{ if
>   (NR==2) $8="9" ;if ($8 == "9") $66="9";print}'

**Input File**

```
024    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 248   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1^M
025    1   1   1   1   1   1       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1       1   1   1   1   1   1^M
026    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1^M
```

**Output File**

```
024    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 248   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
025 1 1 1 1 1 1 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 9 1 1 1 1
026    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat inputfile | awk '$1 ~/^0(1?[0-9])|^00(1?[0-9])$/' | awk '{ if (NR==2) $8="9" ;if ($8 == "9") $66="9";print}'|column -t
```

Comment: how come if 1 line have a lot of 1 1 1 or 0 0 0 . after i add in column -t some of the data are missing? @chenyb999

Comment: column, as it name , can only range output from left to right. if data missing, it can't tell to next line.