# How to resolve replacing in a .txt file and how is the different between window and linux viewing the same files.

Tags: linux, awk, sh

The question i want to ask is how come in window . This .txt file i open it will show a nice format of a wafers. But when i transfer it to linux system and i open it . The format was shifted at column41 and column42. 
Can anyone explain to me. Because i am replacing some of the value in the .txt file but after i replace it . the format run More.

I have post a question at here and when i run basic .txt file it was fine but when i am running .txt file that i show below , the result was spoil. I need some help on this. Many thanks.

[Linux how to make the space similar with previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644415/linux-how-to-make-the-space-similar-with-previous/35644605#35644605)

**.txt that open in Linux system**

```
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   4   4 4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   7   7
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1 2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1

001                                                                                                                                1   1                       1   1    
002                                                                                                    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 1   1   1   1   1
003                                                                                        1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
004                                                                            1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
005                                                                1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 248   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
006                                                        1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
007                                                    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2 1 248   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
008                                            1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 248   1   1   1   1   1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
009                                        1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
010                                1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1
```

**Output after run the script**

```
001  1  1  1  1
002  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1
003  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1
004  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1
005  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  248  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
006  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1    1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
007  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  2  1  248  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
008  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  248  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
009  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
010  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: DOS line ending is `\r\n`, Linux line end is `\n`. You must convert between the two, or otherwise handle the difference in  your code. See the `dos2unix` and `unix2dox` utilities.

Comment: What "script" are you modifying the input file with? Your input seems to be using white space for formatting, which is not being conserved.  (Typically, the amount of white space is not important and _any_ amount is used to as a field delimiter. But here, it is relevant.) Also, what the precise structure of the input? The columns are not evenly spaced when the numbers use multiple digits. Does it contain tabs too? A different format using place holders might be easier to work with.  Whatever you tool generates your data, could you possibly export to something easier to use, like CSV?

Comment: I don't see any awk code in this question, but if you want to control for DOS line endings, put this in the beginning of the code (though after a `BEGIN {…}` stanza): `{ gsub(/\r/, "") }`